# Answering and upvoting old questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, chat

Currently we have quite a bunch of [unanswered and old questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/tor/query/370061/old-unanswered-questions). It would be nice if they could receive an answer and if the person who answers them receives some reputation. Thatswhy I would suggest that whoever answers those questions puts the URL into our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10754/the-exit-node). Other people could log in and upvote the answer. This way we could increase the number of answers. What do you think?